# How do I convert Entry String into int or float?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

how to convert the Entry string into numerical int or float values

```
#========================= Imports files and Widgets 
#===================================================================

from tkinter import *

#========================= Main Window Size 
main_window = Tk()
main_window.title("Entry Input Test")

width = 400
height = 200
main_window.geometry(str(width) + "x" + str(height) + "+600+520")
main_frame=Frame(main_window)

################ Varibles 

VarWidthECC = 20

################ Input Boxes
```

how to convert the Entry input string into a int or float values

```
First_Value=Label(main_frame,text="Enter First Value ")
First_Value.grid(row=10,column=5, padx=10, sticky=E)
First_Value=(Entry(main_frame, width=VarWidthECC, justify='right'))
#First_Value=Input(main_frame, width=VarWidthECC, justify='right')
First_Value.grid(row=10,column=6, padx=10, pady=0)

Second_Value=Label(main_frame,text="Enter Second Value ")
Second_Value.grid(row=20,column=5, padx=10, sticky=E)
Second_Value=Entry(main_frame, width=VarWidthECC, justify = 'right')
#Second_Value=Input(main_frame, width=VarWidthECC, justify = 'right')
Second_Value.grid(row=20,column=6, padx=20, pady=10)

################ Comparison Function 

def Enter_Button():

    #global First_Value, Second_Value

    print("First Value is: " + First_Value.get())
    print("Second Value is: " + Second_Value.get())
    #value = int(First_Value)
    print(type(First_Value))
```

how to convert the Entry string into numerical int or float values

```
    #Multiply_test = int(First_Value) * 5  #this line of code is Error
    #How can I convert Entry string into int or float??
```

the Multiply test below works
        Multiply_test = 6 * 6
        print("Multiply_test is: " + str(Multiply_test))

```
################ Run Button ####################################
button_enter = Button(main_frame, width=20, background="light grey", 
text=" Enter ", font="Verdana 10 bold", command=Enter_Button, bd=6, 
relief='raise')
button_enter.grid(row=100, column=6, padx=10, pady=5)

####################################################

main_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)       # Prints out Labels on Main Window
main_window.mainloop()                # Code to End Main Window (root)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `.get()` method gives the input of the entry in the form of the string. You are trying to convert the tkinter entry to float/int but you forgot to use the `get` method.

Replace the `Enter_Button()` with this and try:

```
def Enter_Button():

    #global First_Value, Second_Value

    print("First Value is: " + First_Value.get())
    print("Second Value is: " + Second_Value.get())
    #value = int(First_Value)
    print(type(First_Value.get()))   #< Use get method as you used it above
    print(type(int(First_Value.get())))
    print(type(float(First_Value.get())))
```

Comment: Thank you very much,  your code works great.                                                                                                                        
                       
    print(type(int(First_Value.get())))
    print(type(float(First_Value.get())))

Answer (score 0):

`.get()` returned an `str` object , we already know python uses `.` for float identication.

```
if '.' in First_Value.get():
    # You got an Float
    return float(First_Value.get()) # Never reached to else for TYPE error
else :
    #You got an Integer
    return int(First_Value.get())
```

Actually this not an total soulotion, [check this .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float)